# SWIFT: Why I can't get the current URL loaded in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, url, swift, webview

I need to get the current URL loaded into the webview and this is how I'm trying to get that but it gives me this error: "Cannot convert the exporessions type 'ST7??' to type 'String'

and this is the code

```
 var currentURL : NSString = webView.request?.URL.absoluteString!
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you put parentheses around this, the error goes away:

```
let currentURL : NSString = (webView.request?.URL.absoluteString)!
```

Comment: SWIFT 3 -- let currentURL = self.webView.request?.url?.absoluteString

Answer (score 3):

Beware that yours might not be just a syntax problem.
If your webView is in a state where `request == nil` your app will crash at runtime.

I'd rather write something like:

```
if let currentURL = webView.request?.URL.absoluteString {

    // do things ...
    // Your currentURL will be automatically bridged to Swift's String type 

} else {

   // Just in case request is nil ...

}
```