# Swift: How to put current URL from UIWebView into UITextField?

Tags: swift, url, uiwebview, uitextfield

(XCode 6.3.2, Swift 1.2)  I simply want to put the URL of the loaded webpage of the UIWebView into an UITextField. The solutions which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549661/swift-why-i-cant-get-the-current-url-loaded-in-uiwebview) doesn't work for me.

Here's my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var addressBar: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

//some more code...

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
   self.addressBar.text = (self.webView.request?.URL.absoluteString)!
}
```

Swift Compiler Error: *Value of optional type 'NSURL?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?*

Any ideas or hints would be very appreciated.
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
The answer from *Airspeed Velocity* works for me (see working code below). However I  recognized that sometimes the loaded URL isn't correctly written back to the UITextField.
It's reproducible for example on Vimeo.
When I click on a video link on vimeo.com the URL should change to something like: https://vimeo.com/105060039
On mobile Safari this works fine but not on the UIWebView. To the URL "https://vimeo.com/" the video number isn't added.
What I'm doing wrong? Is there an other possibility to get the current URL?

```
@IBOutlet weak var addressBar: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

//some more code...

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
   addressBar.text = webView.request?.URL?.absoluteString
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`webView.request` is optional, so you’re using optional chaining.  You just need to do the same with the request’s `URL`, which is also optional:

```
self.addressBar.text = self.webView.request?.URL?.absoluteString
```

Note, there’s no need to force-unwrap this with the `!` on the end.  This is because `self.addressBar.text` is itself of type `String?`.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.2**

self.addressBar.text = self.webView.request?.url?.absoluteString